# how to Take images from a server by my wasit server?

Tags: php

i want to retrieve images from an other server by my server (wasit server) and send it to client.
i used this structure:

test.html:

```
<img src="test2.php?img=http://the server/img/a.jpg">
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

but it dont work.

why? please help me !!!

Comment: When accessing the page normally from the browser, does it work well? Also, why not simply link to the original image from the original server?

Comment: If you aren't doing anything with the image, why not just echo it as-is right back out to the client?  You keep image quality, and require almost no system resources.  Also, be careful not to open yourself up as a wide-open proxy.  Have a white-list of servers.

Comment: this action isnt my final goal. my goal is something else. but for it i must learn how to recover/retrieve pics from other server by my server and send it to client.

Comment: the wasit server is same myself server that must retrieve pics from other servers and send them to client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen your error logs?

You may be facing at least one of these problems (may be others too):

- You don't have GD library (properly) installed.

  - But if you do: What version of this library have you installed?
- In your `php.ini`, you have set this: `allow_url_fopen=0`

The last error forbids you to load images from outside your server.

If you give us what your error log says about your script, we will be able to help you better.